# how to set permission the manager in openldap?

Tags: openldap, access-control-list

i want 2 rule. 
rule1. userpassword,shadowlastchange,description,sshpublickey attrs is self update.
rule2. some account set manage permission.

I make some rules. rule1 is successful but rule2 is failed.

```
# cat bdb-test.acl
dn: olcDatabase={2}bdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: to attrs=userpassword,shadowlastchange,description,sshpublickey
        by self write
        by anonymous auth
        by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write
        by * read
olcAccess: to *
        by dn="cn=Manager,dc=sample,dc=com" write
        by group="cn=ea-manager,ou=sysGroup,dc=sample,dc=com" write
        by * read
```

ea-manager is this. i want sysuser1,2 set manager permission(account create,modify,delete, assign set member to group)

```
dn: cn=ea-manager,ou=sysGroup,dc=sample,dc=com
cn: ea-manager
gidNumber: 9000
objectClass: posixGroup
objectClass: top
memberUid: sysuser1
memberUid: sysuser2
```

Comment: i'm solved. by set="[cn=ldapadmin,ou=sysGroup,dc=sample,dc=com]/memberUid" write

Comment: by set="[cn=ldapadmin,ou=sysGroup,dc=sample,dc=com]/memberUid & user/uid" write <br> this correct